# Where does "liblzma.so.0" come from?

Tags: software-installation, docker

I got this:

```
error while loading shared libraries: liblzma.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install liblzma5
sudo apt-get install liblzma-dev
```

but they didn't work. How to install the missing shared library file?

**EDIT:**

I built my system from scratch from the following docker file.

```
FROM biocontainers/biocontainers:latest

USER root

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y vim
RUN apt-get install -y sudo

RUN conda install -y bwa
RUN conda install -y GATK
RUN conda install -y samtools
RUN conda install -y picard=2.3.0

WORKDIR /protocol
```

Comment: What program are you trying to run, and what is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: @steeldriver 16.04. A C++ program requires it to run.

Comment: I believe the liblzma5 package installs /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0. You may need to make a link to it.

Answer (score 2):

`liblzma.so.0` was used by an older version of liblzma, I think before v5 (which was released around 2010).

Try to compile v4.999.9beta from https://tukaani.org/xz/old.html

Symlinking `liblzma.so.5` to `liblzma.so.0` may work or cause segfaults or other errors.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download xz-utils from tukaani.org

2. Extract tarfile
  `$ tar -xvf xz-*.tar.gz`

3. Build
   `$ cd xz*`
   `$ ./configure && make`

4. Install
  `$ sudo make install`

5. Reconfigure dynamic linker bindings
  `$ sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib`

Now pacman should work again. Install xz-utils using pacman:

`$ sudo pacman -S core/xz-utils`

Now you can uninstall the manually installed xz-utils by vising its source directory and:

`$ sudo make uninstall`

Source directory and the downloaded tarfile can now be removed and everything should be in order.

edit: Just to be safe, do another pacman -S core/xz-utils after removing the manually installed packet.

The actual thread is here,
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=77382